# Plug-in fragment does not see packages in host plug-in

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-classpath

I am writing a test fragment which tests classes in the host plug-in. One class to be tested uses `org.joda.time.DateTime` and I need to reference joda in the fragment.

The host contains the joda JAR, the joda packages are on the classpath and are exported.

However, in the fragment, I can't see any joda packages and get compile errors.

What can I do?

Comment: Why is Joda an included JAR instead of a plugin of its own, as is recommended? Please share a minimal example with which the issue can be reproduced with the current Eclipse via GitHub, GitLab, etc.

Comment: @howlger I couldn't find a joda plugin anywhere so I made my own. This solved the problem for me.